# Restrict typescript to insure reference to 'any' object's properties is checked

Tags: typescript, object, any

I have a JS object `myObject`, which is of type `any` (I can't change the type, since it comes from a library).

If I try to access a property from `myObject` I get no errors from typescript, since its type is `any`. But `myObject` could be undefined, and cause a crash.

Is it possible to get typescript to give an error in this case?

For example:

```js
console.log(myObject.myProperty) // <-- if myObject is undefined, this will crash.
```

What I would like:

```js
console.log(myObject.myProperty) // <-- typescript gives error
console.log(myObject?.myProperty) // <-- typescript gives no error
```

Is there a tsconfig for changing this behavior?

---

I am not looking for a solution using type `unknown`.

Comment: I'm confused; if you can't change the type, what can anyone do? Maybe you're looking for a linter setting or something?  Can you copy the value to a new variable whose type you *can* change, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxaDKW)?

Comment: For example, there is a tsconfig setting for `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, which provides a way to avoid "cannot read property of undefined". I was curios if there was a similar setting for objects of type any. In short, if the program could crash, typescript should warn us about it.

Comment: Ah, as far as I know there is no such compiler setting.  Are you looking for a linter setting that gives you this behavior or would that be out of scope?  (I don't know much about eslint, but someone who does might be able to help you if that is in scope for the question)

Comment: Ok, thank you for that information:) Maybe linting is the way to go. Maybe this will be implemented in ts in the future!

Comment: The problem is that `any` intentionally turns off type checking.  Making `any` stricter than that isn't part of the language.  Most of the efforts I've seen have been trying to make people move away from `any`.  I'm still looking through the GitHub issues to see if anyone has made such a feature request before, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TypeScript does not have support for a stricter interpretation of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) in which member access is disallowed unless it is known to be safe.  Nor have I found any existing request for this particular feature.  There was a proposal for a `--strictAny`, which would have been different, but this was eventually closed in [microsoft/TypeScript#24737](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24737) saying, among other things, that extra complexity around `any` really didn't seem to be worth it, especially because there are many places in real world code where `any` is intentionally used *as a way to turn off type checking*.   So it is unlikely that TypeScript will add such functionality.

Instead, you could use a linter, like [TypeScript ESLint](https://typescript-eslint.io).  There is a [`no-unsafe-member-access` rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-member-access/) which "disallows member access on any variable that is typed as `any`".  This will cause the desired error to appear, but it will also cause undesired errors where you have done the proper type check.  That is, it is more restrictive than you want:

```
declare const myObject: any;
myObject.myProperty // warning: unsafe access 
myObject?.myProperty // warning: unsafe access ☹
```

It doesn't look like there's any "perfect" way to proceed.  I'd recommend that you copy the value to a variable of a non-`any` type:

```
type MyAny = { [k: string]: any } | undefined | null;
const _myObject: MyAny = myObject
_myObject.myProperty; // error
_myObject?.myProperty; // okay
```

Or write a type checking function that narrows `any` to more safely indexable type:

```
function nonNullish(x: any): x is { [k: string]: any } {
  return x != null;
}
if (nonNullish(myObject)) {
  myObject.myProperty // okay
}
```

Or maybe even push back on the typings provider for the library and say that `any` is too loose of a type if the value might really be `undefined` or `null` at runtime.  (If it *can't*, then the other option is to just stop worrying about it until and unless it does happen.)

[TS-ESLint Playground link to code](https://typescript-eslint.io/play#ts=4.9.3&sourceType=module&code=CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWwJ4HkAjAK3AwC54oVcBuAWACg8jSwMA6PABRiQAcQMDLngB6MfADusFAEsUAc0oBXdFABmCKGDAg0aeIF4NwFB7TFiTIB+Lrl4ChI8ZJkx5S1eq1Vd+w4E4yJiYRQXgAWVwAQRp4AF54AG94AG0Aa0pMGAVFAF1KalEAX3gAH3g1UA0FEGBS+BQVCAgGRmR0LAB9CzYKcKiY+O6yJi6CS3Zbe0FhOmd4IT4YEaH2Gx4+aZFaOaRUqFwgxg01djlUetQAOUaIOTQACwAKAA98mgBKSmf4O8SU9PgmWyeSoMWKCSY8HgcAwKjc8G+AEJ4g0mi1Ckw5Bp4I8UFcbncnisMO93olITgxj1JhtHKIJPBdvsmBjGEwgA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tieQEMAZoloBbRCIBGiaLT5kyKVBkgB3PtCaRwYAL4g9IIA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)

Comment: I think, as you suggest, that feedback to the typings provider is the best way to go forward. The library in question is the npm package 'next' from vercel, and the exported type `NextApiRequest`.

Thank you!